# How to create New Server in Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, instance

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017. After the installation completed, I launched the Studio. It asked me for server name. How can I create a new server?  [click here to view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUbWW.png)

Comment: Hi @Muhammad - You would use the installation software to install the server software : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 - since this is not a programming question per se, the question will be closed quite rapidly, but the above should be your starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not. SQL Server is a software that is INSTALLED on servers. Same like ordering a new phone (ssms) does not magically create a phone provider (sql server).

Either you get access to it (download MS, i.e.) or your company / school provides you with the database and access credentials. Which include server name.